# Android Login authentication with Spring boot server

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I'm working on an android app where I need to login and register. I've created the server side using the java spring boot framework. Registration works well, but I cannot login. How can I solve? The code I wrote is as follows:
**Server code for register:**

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public Person addUser(@RequestBody Person user) {
    user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    return userService.saveUser(user);
}
```

**Server code for login:**

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public UserDetails authenticate(@RequestBody Person principal) throws Exception {
    return authService.authenticate(principal);
}
```

And this works well. Because if I try with postman, I can log well.

[This is postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs51Q.jpg)

Also, registration with andorid works weel too. If I register an user from android, it'll be save into my db and with postman i can log with that user.

[This is my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVAB.jpg)

**This is my andorid code for registration:**

```
class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Person> {

        @Override
        protected Person doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "myurl/register";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Person person= new Person();
                person.setNome(myname);
                person.setCognome(myusername);
                person.setUsername(mynickname);
                person.setPassword(mypassword);
                person.setProfileType(myprofileType);
                return restTemplate.postForObject(url, person, Person.class);
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And it works well.

**This is my android code for login:**

```
 class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Person> {

    @Override
    protected Person doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "myurl/login";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Person person= new Person();
            person.setUsername(myusername);
            person.setPassword(mypassword);
            return restTemplate.postForObject(url, person, Person.class); 
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Login does not work.

Should I use Spring boot for android?

Does anyone have an example?

Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must send your auth token in the header. This sould be accomplished with an interceptor like this

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    public static final String TAG = "INTERCEPTOR";

    @Bean
    EgomniaLoginManager loginManager;

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.set(ACCESS_TOKEN, loginManager.getAccessToken());

        // logga request
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            this.logRequest(request, body);
        }

        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);

        // logga response
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
//            this.logResponse(response);
            // execute second time because logging consume response body
//            response = execution.execute(request, body);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

You must add this interceptor to your `RestTemplate`, I use Android Annotations to do that, so I don't remember how it could be done